# How can I get jQuery-UI sliders to work with non numerical values?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have read through the API documentation and everything refers to numbers

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

Is it possible to make a slider non numerical for example January - December and how would I go about doing this/are there any examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this working <kbd>[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/NetRS/)</kbd> here.

```
$(function () {
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    $('#slider').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 11,
        step: 1,
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $('#selectedMonth').text(months[0]);
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $('#selectedMonth').text(months[ui.value]);
        }
    });
});
```

Concerning your example with the months it would be an easy way to create an array. Using the `slide` event you could easily use the `ui.value` value to choose an element of the array. To don't allow any selection for which there is no month (>12) use the `max` option and set it to 11. `min` is 0 of course because the array starts with index 0.

I just added the `create` event to fill the `selectedMonth` span with a month before a user first uses the slider.

For completeness the doc references:

- [min](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-min)
- [max](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-max)
- [step](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-step)
- [create](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-create)
- [slide](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)